# How can I divide a semicircular border radius in half?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

How can I divide the yellow line by 2 or how can I remove the yellow line above the red box?

I just want the yellow line below. Is it possible to solve that with only using HTML and CSS? Do I have to use JS for that?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animasyon 2s linear infinite normal paused;
}

.ring {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: none solid none none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.content::after {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
}

@keyframes animasyon {
  0% {
    transform: rotate( 0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate( 90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate( 180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate( 270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate( 360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo Don't impose your personal programming style on someone else's question

Comment: I'm new here. I'm really sorry if I make some mistake about rules. I did not understand what you guys talking about but I fixed my problem through clip-path:polygon. ty...

Comment: @Lennholm you should refrain from enacting laws that do not exist, especially when they go against minor freedoms

Answer (score 0):

I changed the HTML a bit, it now looks like this. Is the result what you expected ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  animation: animasyon 2s linear infinite normal paused;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring {
  border: 5px solid goldenrod;
  border-style: none solid none none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 50% 0 0 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content::after {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
}

@keyframes animasyon {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="ring"></div>
</div>
```